# Redefining `\global\long\def` to always use `\robustify`

Tags: macros, robust-commands

I use LyX and the math macros are compiled to LaTeX using `\global\long\def\mymacro#1#2{body}` (for a binary macro). This leads to me having to `\robustify` many of those macros.

I tried redefining `\def` and `\global` without much success, a priori because macros have different arities. Is there some (somewhat) simple way of automagically `\robustify`ing all macros defined with `\global\long\def`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using `\newcommand` or `\newrobustcmd` here? That would work fine, other than the `\global` that seems a bit odd anyway.

Comment: Can you please show an example of where you find macros defined via `\global\long\def`? Is LyX doing this way? If so, I have another reason for staying far from it.

Comment: Never try to redefine `\def`! It is one of TeX's basic commands.

Comment: @JosephWright @egreg I write stuff in the LyX editor because I find it very useful when editing big math formulas / tables etc. The LyX file is then transformed to LaTeX (that's where the `\global\long\def` appears), and then the LaTeX is compiled. I therefore have 3 solutions: (1) Add `\robustify\mymacro` everywhere by hand. (2) Write something in LaTeX that redefines one of those commands so that compiled macros are robust. (3) Edit the LyX source code. And I'd really prefer (2) if it's possible.

Comment: How do you define these macros that are translated to `\global\long\def`? Please add a small example of your LyX code and the translated .tex file to your question.